# How do you insert a cartoDB map using Cartodb.js into a wordpress site?

Tags: carto, wordpress, carto-js

I've been looking at http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html so that I can put a customized map into a wordpress site.

I've been copying and pasting the following code into the wordpress text editor. However, it is not displaying a map on my website.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5/viz.json');
</script>
```

How do I display a map in wordpress, using cartodb.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in your own hosted version of a Wordpress site, as @iriberri has suggested, I will assume you have your own hosting account for files separate from your Wordpress site, that is, you can create directories on your web server and host HTML, CSS and JS files, etc.

Assuming this, you should be able to create the map you want to embed on your site as a full-frame HTML page (ie. the map goes to 100% width and height of the HTML page), and include all the custom functionality you want to show on the wordpress page in which the map is to be embedded (ie. the code you referenced above).

Once this simple map page has been built, upload the files to your web server in a directory structure like `http://yoursever/simplemap/myMap.html`

With this HTML page built, you should, again as iriberri suggested, use an iFrame to simply embed the `myMap.html` into your Wordpress post like this:

```
<iframe src="http://yoursever/simplemap/myMap.html" height="100" width="200"></iframe>
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an own hosted WordPress, you can just include the HTML iframe code that you will find in the sharing wizard.

The free version of WordPress.org doesn't allow including embedded code.

Comment: I want to embed a more customized, interactive map. I know that this means using the cartodb.js library, I'm just not sure how to go about it!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress.com now recognizes CartoDB as another 'media' source. Just paste in the link to your map and Wordpress will make the iframe for you.

[image: img]

Here it is working: https://andrewxhill.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/a-day-of-wordpress-com-on-twitter/